# If I use Medi-Gel or a Cobra rocket in a mission and then quit, do I lose it?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When I'm in a multiplayer mission and then quit, I forfeit any XP and cash that I might have earned.

Tonight, I played a MP mission and used a rocket launcher to kill a Banshee and a Brute at the same time (I was very proud of myself), but then I got an important phone call and had to quit the mission. I was a little sad about the XP loss, but I was quite sad about my missile.  But then I thought, "Maybe my missile didn't get recorded as used if I didn't finish the mission?"

**When are consumable items such as medi-gel and rockets marked as expended during a multiplayer mission, at the moment of use or after the mission is over?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you use it, you've used it. However if you rejoin the mission before it ends, you'll still contribute for the other players and get credit! I'd suggest in a currently going mission rather than quitting, run to the extraction point and let yourself die there. That way the group can theoretically still get a full extraction.